# analytic evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\mathrm{Bi}(x)}$

Tags: special-functions, definite-integrals

So, just out of random curiosity, I'm trying to find an analytic expression for the following definite integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\mathrm{Bi}(x)}$$.

Where $\mathrm{Bi}(x)$ is the [Airy Bi function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctions.html). Wolfram alpha gives a very messy series for $\frac{1}{\mathrm{Bi}(x)}$, and I couldn't find the numerical evaluation of it in either Plouffe's inverter or the Inverse Symbolic Calculator. evaluation by mpmath below:

```
>>> quad(lambda x: 1/airybi(x), [0,inf])
mpf('1.9365573326233994')
```

Comment: How about calling it deoxygerbe's constant?

Comment: Though it's not very useful, we can represent the integrand with Bessel functions: $$\sqrt[6]{\frac{16}{3}} \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{-2/3} dt}{I_{1/3} (t) +I_{-1/3} (t)}$$